# How to say a interrogative sentence of future perfect tense?

Tags: future-perfect

> You will have worked tonight.

Which auxiliary verb should I change to before subject? **will** or **will have**?

Comment: I've heard "Will have you worked tonight?" form before, but only towards people named Will.

Answer (score 2):

Will you have finished your report by next Tuesday's meeting?